# How do you specify a local docker image or repository when using dockertest in Go?

Tags: go

I am using dockertest to build and run containers for testing out my go code.  I have a specific image I built for testing file interactions.

According to the dockertest examples I can do something like this:

```
pool, err := dockertest.NewPool("")
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("Could not connect to docker: %s", err)
}

// Build and run the given Dockerfile
resource, err := pool.BuildAndRun("my-test-image", "./db/image/Dockerfile", []string{})
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("Could not start resource: %s", err)
}
      
// When you're done, kill and remove the container
err = pool.Purge(resource)
```

...to spin up a new container based on an image.  However, this assumes I am pushing my image to a remote repo.

My question is how do I specify to use a local image or image repo?

Comment: you can set up a local docker repo